# how to implement a side navigation in angular?

Tags: angular

I have defined a page (using routing) which takes a file as an input and uploads it.
It also shows the progress of the uploaded file using progressbar.
Here is the code.:

file.component.html:

```
<div class="container"  (fileDropped)="onFileDropped($event)">
    <input type="file" #fileDropRef id="fileDropRef" multiple (change)="fileBrowseHandler($event.target.files)" />

    <h3>Drag and drop file here</h3>
    <h3>or</h3>
    <label for="fileDropRef">Browse for file</label>
</div>


<div class="files-list">
    <div class="single-file" *ngFor="let file of files; let i = index">
        <div class="file-icon" style="width: 50px">         
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <h4 class="name">
                {{ file?.name }}
            </h4>   

            <app-progress [progress]="file?.progress"></app-progress>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

here is file.component.ts:

```
import { ProgressComponent } from './../progress/progress.component';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-comp',
  templateUrl: './file-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-comp.component.css']
})
export class FileCompComponent implements OnInit {
  files: any[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  fileBrowseHandler(files) {
    this.prepareFilesList(files);
  }
  prepareFilesList(files: Array<any>) {
    for (const item of files) {
      item.progress = 0;
      this.files.push(item);
    }
    this.uploadFilesSimulator(0);

}
uploadFilesSimulator(index: number) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (index === this.files.length) {
      return;
    } else {
      const progressInterval = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.files[index].progress === 100) {
          clearInterval(progressInterval);
          this.uploadFilesSimulator(index + 1);
        } else {
          this.files[index].progress += 5;
        }
      }, 200);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
onFileDropped($event) {
  this.prepareFilesList($event);
}
}
```

My requirement is that I want to show the progress and name of the file in a sidedrawer INSTEAD OF div below.
How can i do it? any suggestion.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp ? The sidenav is a plain styled div.

Comment: Use html grid with 2 colums. It's 100% responsive.